# How do i format time in php

Tags: php

I have a time returned from database in php as  92500. But  i want to format the time  as 09:25 how can do this `echo date ('H:i',strtotime($row['time']))` .it is outputting 00:00. How can i get 09:25

Comment: Your code works for me, if I use "9:25" for $row['time']. You should start by checking that the row actually contains the value you expect.

Comment: What field type do you have into your database? And what's inside `$row['time']` exactly?

Comment: ARe you sure the output of your $row['time'] is correct?

Comment: Check the format of `$row['time']`.

Comment: @jondavidjohn will break any hour  10+

Comment: @Someone: What exactly is the output of `$row['time']`.

Comment: @Rocket:92500 is the database returned value

Comment: @Someone: That's not a valid time value.  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php

Comment: ouch, why do people do such crazy things

Answer (score 27):

Actually

```
$date = '9:25';

echo date ('H:i',strtotime($date));
```

is working perfectly fine for me.

Returns "09:25".

So i guess it has to be some error with your database value meaning $row['time'] doesn't contain the right value.

Comment: But in the database it is storing as 92500 which i want to get 09:25 in this way

Comment: @Someone: I don't think `92500` is a valid time value.

Comment: ye 92500 is no a valid time value is it :) (Did you try to save it as a timestamp?)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function formatSeconds($secs=0){
    $units = array('Sec', 'Min', 'Hrs', 'Days', 'Months', 'Years'); 
    if($secs<60){
        $time=$secs;
        $pow=0;
    }
    else if($secs>=60 && $secs<3600){
        $time=$secs/60;
        $pow=1;            
    }
    else if($secs>=3600 && $secs<86400){
        $time=$secs/3600;
        $pow=2;            
    }
    else if($secs>=86400 && $secs<2592000){
        $time=$secs/86400;
        $pow=3;            
    }
    else if($secs>=2592000 && $secs<31104000){
        $time=$secs/2592000;
        $pow=4;            
    }
    else if($secs>=31104000 ){
        $time=$secs/31104000;
        $pow=5;            
    }

    return round($time) . ' ' . $units[$pow]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

g 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 1 through 12

Use PHP date itself

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The OP is using `date()` and *wants* leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You said `$row['time']` was "number type".  Do you mean that it's a timestamp?  If so, you don't need `strtotime`.

```
echo date('H:i', $row['time'])
```

The value `92500` is not a valid time value for `strtotime()`.  See [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) for valid time values.

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways:

```
$time = '92500'; // HHMMSS

if (strlen($time) == 5)
  $time = '0'.$time;

echo substr($time, 0, 2).':'.substr($time, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this simple function to convert 24 hours time to 12 hour time including "AM" and "PM"

```
<?php 
echo change_time("00:10");               // call the change_function("user input here")
?>
function change_time($input_time)
{
// 23:24    
//break time
$hours = substr($input_time,0,2);
$mins = substr($input_time,3,2);

if (($hours >= 12) && ($hours <= 24))
{
    if (($hours == 24))
    {
        $new_hour = "00";
        $part = "AM";
    }
    else {
        $new_hour = $hours - 12;
        $part = "PM";
    }

}
else
{
    //$new_hour = $hours - 12;
$new_hour = $hours;
    $part = "AM";
}


return $new_hour .":" . $mins ." " . $part . "(".$input_time .")";
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure how this actually answers the question... The question was not asking how to convert from 12 hour to 24 hour.